# Can you create a chooser for several ```ActivityResultLauncher``` objects?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

As a bit of background info, my team is working on a project where users need to upload photos and/or videos. Basically, when someone clicks on the upload button, they get a chooser intent (`Intent.createChooser()`), from which they choose one of several activities (such as GET_CONTENT to upload an existing photo, one to snap one with the camera, etc.) Once an intent is selected, the `startActivityForResult` method gets called and a callback method in the host activity processes the output. And that has worked nicely for us, but now the `startActivityForResult` method is deprecated and I figured we should migrate to the `ActivityResultLauncher` / `registerForActivityResult` pattern before our old approach stops working. And my teammates and I really like how the new way of doing things doesn't depend on the parent activity as much, which makes encapsulation a lot easier and more failsafe. However, we're not sure how to create a chooser for several `ActivityResultLauncher` items. How exactly do people usually do it? It feels like we have a pretty common use case (uploading photos and videos from various sources), but StackOverflow and similar resources are saturated with the now-deprecated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose **extend** of **ActivityResultContract<I, O>** is what you need.

try:

```
public static class GetContentWithChooser extends ActivityResultContract<Pair<String, String>, Uri> {

    @NonNull @NotNull @Override public Intent createIntent(@NonNull @NotNull Context context, Pair<String, String> input) {
        Intent getContentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        getContentIntent.setType(input.first);
        getContentIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType(input.first);
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getContentIntent, input.second);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});
        return chooserIntent;
    }

    @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable @Override public SynchronousResult<Uri> getSynchronousResult(@NonNull @NotNull Context context, Pair<String, String> input) {
        return super.getSynchronousResult(context, input);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public final Uri parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return null;
        return intent.getData();
    }
}
```

and call it further as:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Pair<String,String>> pickFromGalleryLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new GetContentWithChooser(),
            result -> {
                if (result != null) cropFile(result);
            }
    );
```

where Pair<String, String> is media type and title for chooser

```
pickFromGalleryLauncher.launch(Pair.create("image/*", "Select voucher"));
```

But you are right, Intent choosers should have native support, or maybe I missed something.